# Function to get multiple soups only gives one soup

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping

so I am trying to create a function that creates a list of multiple soups. I started with doing it in `normal` code (I do not know how to call this exactly:

```
list_url = ["http://www.facebook.com", "https://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com"]

list_soup = []
for url in list_url:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
    list_soup.append(soup)
```

And this code works, but when I a function of this:

```
def get_multi_soup(list_url):
    list_multi = []
    for url in list_url:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
        list_multi.append(soup)
        return list_multi

list_soup = get_multi_soup(list_url)
```

The code does not work as intended as it only gives one soup instead of three.

Can somebody explain why this does not work? The list_soup equals only one soup.

Comment: your returning from the function at the end of the first loop so you never process any other urls. Move the return to be outside the for loop

Comment: Start debugger and check your code step by step. You will clearly see your fault, and by the way learn how to use debugger :). It will help you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just move the return outside the for loop.
You are returning on the first iteration.

```
def get_multi_soup(list_url):
    list_multi = []
    for url in list_url:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
        list_multi.append(soup)
    return list_multi

list_soup = get_multi_soup(list_url)
```

Should do the trick. :)